# why Munkres didn't say that $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$ , the function is not one-one instead of onto?

Tags: general-topology

**Munkres Theorem $27.7$**

> Let $X$ be a nonempty compact Hausdorff  space .If $X$ has  no isloated point, then $X$ is uncountable

It is written that

> we show that  given $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$ , the function is not onto . It follows  that  $X$ is uncountable

My  confusion :  why Munkres  didn't say  that $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$ , the function is not **one-one** instead of onto ?

I  think  if   $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$ is not one one $\implies   X$  is uncountable because $f(n)$ cannot be put in one-one correspondence with the natural numbers.

Comment: If it is not onto for any function $f$, then there is no bijection, hence $X$ is of higher cardinality than $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: “One-to-one correspondence” means bijective, not injective.

Comment: You can have an injection from a smaller set to a larger set because there’s enough “space” in the larger set for each point of the smaller set to go somewhere different.  You can’t have a surjection since there aren’t enough points in the smaller set to “cover” the larger set.

Comment: okay@JustANoob that mean  $f$  can be one one but not  onto  .Am i right ?

Comment: okay @MichaelBurr

Comment: You can think of $f$ as being even 1-1 if you like. If you can show that no injection from $\Bbb N$ is surjective it follows that there is in particular no bijection between $X$ and $\Bbb N$ so $X$ is not countably infinite, hence uncountable.

Comment: Any constant function $f : \mathbb N \to X$ is not one-to-one, and yet $X$ can be countable. For example, the function $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ given by $f(n)=1$ is not one-to-one, and yet $\mathbb N$ is countable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncountable means "strictly greater than countable" which, by definition, means there is an injection $\mathbb{N}\to X$ but no bijection $\mathbb{N}\to X$. This condition is equivalent to: there is no surjection $\mathbb{N}\to X$ (as a consequence of [Cantor-Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)).

> I  think  if   $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$ is not one one $\implies   X$  is uncountable

On the contrary, consider what happens when say $X=\{0,1\}$. Then no function $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$ is injective. Does this imply that $X$ is uncountable?

No, in fact if $X$ is such that no function $\mathbb{N}\to X$ is injective, then $X$ is finite. It is the exact opposite of what Munkres is trying to show.

Answer (score 3):

Classic facts (assuming choice):

> There exists an injection $f:\Bbb N \to X$ iff $X$ is infinite (countable or uncountable).

> There exists a surjection $f:\Bbb N \to X$ iff $X$ is at most countable.

The equivalence of the latter (by negating both statements) is:

> There exists no surjection from $\Bbb N \to X$ iff $X$ is uncountable.

So that's what Munkres goes for.